# Tabindex is not reaching to lastrow in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

**I have Gridview with 2 textbox..i have setted the tab index for 1st texbox of rows...It

is working fine for all of the rows except last row..it is stopping before the last row..

It is not reaching at last row...

plz,help....**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="st_id" HeaderText="Id" SortExpression="st_id" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Attended-OutOff">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbattendedlectures"  runat="server" Height="27px" Width="32px"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>

                  <td>
                                     <asp:TextBox ID="tbtotalattendence" runat="server" Height="27px" Width="32px" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
                 </td>
                  </tr>
                  </table>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                 </asp:GridView>

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {


                Label batch = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbbatch");
                batch.Text = dpbatchname.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
                Label subject = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbsubject");
                subject.Text = dpsubjname.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();

                Label sessional = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lbcurrentsessional");
                sessional.Text = dpsessional.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
                TextBox total = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("tbtotalattendence");
                total.Text = tbnooflecture.Text.ToString();
               /* TextBox attendence = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("tbattendedlectures");
                attendence.Text = tbnooflecture.Text.ToString();
                */



                SetTabIndexes();
            }
        }

    private void SetTabIndexes()
    {
        short currentTabIndex = 0;
        GridView1.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;

        foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
        {

            TextBox inputField1 = (TextBox)gvr.FindControl("tbattendedlectures");
            inputField1.TabIndex = ++currentTabIndex;

        }


    }
```